# How to programmatically take a screenshot in iOS?

Tags: ios, screenshot

How can I programmatically take a screenshot of the entire screen (iPhone) and save it to the photo library in iOS? There is nothing on the screen other than some labels and a button.

The button is named "ScreenshotButton" that needs to trigger this.

- Do I still need to import QuartzCore?
- Where exactly would I need to place the Screenshot Function in the ViewController?

Answer (score 1):

You need CoreGraphics.  Here's the code I use within the IBAction of a button:

```
CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

CGSize imageSize = rect.size;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, [self.view.layer affineTransform]);

if ([self.view respondsToSelector:@selector(drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:)]) { // iOS 7+
    [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
} else { // iOS 6
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:ctx];
}
screengrab = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screengrab, nil, nil, nil);
```

I define `static UIImage *screengrab;` at the top of my code after @implementation.

You should use Analyze to check for leaks -- I don't have any myself in this code, but CG code always seems to create some.

Answer (score 0):

Hereunder the class used to take snapshot of a view :

```
#import "ScreenSnapshot.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation ScreenSnapshot

static NSUInteger imgNumber;

+ (void)initialize { imgNumber = 0; }

+ (void)saveScreenSnapshot:(UIView *)view {

    UIImage * img = [self screenSnapshotOf:view];
    NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
    imgNumber += 1;

    NSString * fullPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/img_%ld.png",NSHomeDirectory(),imgNumber];

    [data writeToFile:fullPath
           atomically:YES];
}

+ (UIImage *)screenSnapshotOf:(UIView *)view {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [view.layer renderInContext:context];

    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}

@end
```

Copy this code as is in a new class called 'ScreenSnapshot'.

In your "ScreenshotButton" action, write:

```
[ScreenSnapshot saveScreenSnapshot:self.view];
```

...after having imported "ScreenSnapshot.h".

You can replace the location used in my code to store the images and you'll **be able to programmatically take a screenshot in iOS**.